# how to fix Stripe The customer has not entered their payment method in test environment

Tags: stripe-payments

my issue is I'm a beginner in Stripe API but I'm learning.
My issue is that I would like to create a payment intent using Postman.
It works but in paymebt dashboard I've got the incomplete icon and a message

> The customer has not entered their payment method

Here is a screenshot of postman and what I'm sending :

[image]

When I looked for payment_method,

```
ID of the payment method used in this PaymentIntent.
```

I guess it's the card token to be used but when I use it I have the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "A token may not be passed in as a PaymentMethod. Instead, use payment_method_data with type=card and card[token]=tok_1IL4SzF4hKd41bgRRGY0rM3f.",
        "param": "payment_method",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following this guide [1]. You may swap out certain POST calls using Postman if that makes it easier to test, but the core idea is that a PaymentMethod should be collected using Stripe.js and Elements. This is done securely and gives you the minimum PCI burden. Then, once you have a PaymentMethod (with id format pm_xxx) you can use that to do things like create and confirm a PaymentIntent.

If you would like to simply test the API there are other options too. You can create a PaymentMethod directly against the API like so (you could replicate this in Postman):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods \
  -u sk_test_xxx: \
  -d type=card \
  -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "card[exp_month]"=2 \
  -d "card[exp_year]"=2022 \
  -d "card[cvc]"=314
```

And then pass the resulting ID to the payment_method of the PaymentIntent. Or even use a pre-baked payment method `pm_card_visa`, many of those are listed on this page if you choose the payment method tab [2], and then create a PaymentIntent using it:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
  -u sk_test_xxx: \
  -d amount=2000 \
  -d currency=eur \
  -d "payment_method_types[]"=card \
  -d payment_method='pm_card_visa' \
  -d confirm=true
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. I'm a bit confused because I have created a card token using https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens. I thaught that what should be used to created the card.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I have the message "The customer has not completed the payment.".

Comment: Then the user should confirm the PaymentIntent, that is step 3 in the linked guide. The client_secret of the PaymentIntent should be used in the frontend to confirmCardPayment() using Stripe.js